# Tomcat 7 startup class or listener setup (to initiate RMI registry)

Tags: spring, tomcat, rmi

I have spring apps A, B and C that are running on single Tomcat 7 instance.

A is only entry point and relies on B & C functionality. B and C expose their service bean via rmi.
In future there would be more apps like B and C (D, E ...).

At the moment rmi registry is initiated by A on load via context loader of

```
  <bean id="registry" class="org.springframework.remoting.rmi.RmiRegistryFactoryBean">
    <property name="port" value="${batch.rmi.port}"/>
  </bean>

  <bean id="serverConnector" class="org.springframework.jmx.support.ConnectorServerFactoryBean" depends-on="registry">
    <property name="objectName" value="connector:name=rmi"/>
    <property name="serviceUrl" value="service:jmx:rmi://localhost:${batch.rmi.port}"/>
  </bean>
```

My problem is that when A is restarted rmi registry also is restarted and B & C lose their entry in registry. Moreover on server restart I can't guarantee that A will load before B & C (it is ok so far ... due to naming order?).

**I can't find a mention of ~setting some listener in server.xml so that registry is loaded on server start.** All the google has for me is JmxRemoteLifecycleListener that starts jmx - which I don't want to be running (remote config is discouraged in my case).

*Edit #1*

Apparently I could did so via MBean loaded by org.apache.catalina.mbeans.ServerLifecycleListener ... up to 6, got dropped from 7.

*Edit #2*

Initial temp solution was to manually restart failed apps after restart.
Current temp solution is dedicated app (rmi context only) that has path "a..." (I guess some symbols/numbers would be more suitable) so that Tomcat loads it first. Not pretty but works for now - until there are more "a..." apps or tomcat behavior is changed in next update.

*Edit #3*

B & C are exposed as

```
  <bean id="registry" class="org.springframework.remoting.rmi.RmiRegistryFactoryBean">
    <property name="host" value="${batch.rmi.host}"/>
    <property name="port" value="${batch.rmi.port}"/>
  </bean>

  <bean class="org.springframework.remoting.rmi.RmiServiceExporter">
    <property name="serviceName" value="ExampleBatchJob"/>
    <property name="service" ref="jobLauncherController"/>
    <property name="serviceInterface" value="org.example.IJobLauncherController"/>
    <property name="registry" ref="registry"/>
  </bean>
```

*When host parameter is specified app looks up registry and never attempts to create if not found. Another approach to problem is that there is no setting for RmiRegistryFactoryBean to "lookup registry, initiate one if not found"* -> my misunderstanding, explained by aecolley.

Comment: Are B and C also declared `depends-on="registry"`?

Comment: There are other kinds of LifeCycleListener, in fact you can write your own, but then your solution is Tomcat-specific of course.

Comment: @aecolley added edit #3

Comment: @EJP changed title a little. My problem is that google failed me this time as I can't find minimalist example to derive from.

Comment: You don't need a 'minimalist example'. All you need is the interface definition. Just implement the methods. I haven't looked but I'm prepared to bet there at only two methods, a startup and a stopped method. It isn't hard.

Comment: org.apache.catalina.ContainerListener looks like one that can be hooked up to host or server (~event, not method based). Documentation / examples are "great", single mention of event types - "Note that "container start" and "container stop" events ..."

Answer (score 1):

By hooking the RMIRegistry to A (and nothing else) with `depends-on`, you're assuring that the RMIRegistry will be destroyed shortly after A is destroyed. (See [Spring docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-dependson).)

There is indeed a setting for RmiRegistryFactoryBean to create a registry if one is not found: simply omit the `host` property. However, I suggest making all the registry-using applications depend on the same registry with `depends-on` if possible, to eliminate any randomness about which one gets started first.

Comment: Right, somehow I failed to realize that registry stays in app context (~ not server's) so it gets destroyed. This lead me to being stuck with thought that registry is still active when "repeated" init appears on restart of A. Realizing that I need to check something ...

Comment: I removed "alt approach to problem" - single registry is available via app 0 ("current temp solution" from edit #2). Is there other way to reference registry from multiple apps ... shared global context on server? Allowing any app to have it in its context is not ok due to redeploys, etc.

Comment: I'm not sure if it's possible to declare inter-app dependencies so easily. Frankly, I'd just start a standalone rmiregistry and leave it running.

Comment: Thus original question for ways to get registry running. Standalone can be tricky due to circumstances.